# How to open a URL when you click on a Button?

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I have this problem with a Button. It won't open a URL when you click on it. Don't know what's the problem. I would appreciated if somebody would help. Thanks.

```
public class Tours implements Serializable  {

 private String mId;
 private String mTitle;
 private String mYear;
 private String mCoord;

public Tours(){}

public Tours(String id, String title, String year, String coord) {
    this.mId = id;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mYear = year;
    this.mCoord = coord;
}

public String getId() {return mId;}

public void setId(String id) {this.mId = id;}

public String getTitle() {return mTitle;}

public void setTitle(String title) {this.mTitle = title;}

public String getYear() {return mYear;}

public void setYear(String year) {this.mYear = year;}

public String getCoord() {return mCoord;}

public void  setCoord(String coord) {this.mCoord = coord;}
```

}

Comment: There's no _onClick_ action in your code..

Comment: Where is onClickListener?

Comment: You haven't implemented an onClickListener for your button

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct that mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `oncreateVew()` butterknife initialize place add

```
 @Nullable
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
 container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_fragment, container, 
        false);
        ButterKnife.bind(getActivity(), view);
        return view;

}

@OnClick(R.id.bAbout)
public void someButtonOnClick(View view) {
 String url = "http://www.example.com";
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
 startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of errors when I enter getActivity() as cotext, same for this.

Comment: I did. But there is much more errors, it's too long,It's like whole app is wrong, and I know it's not the case.I mean, I have other fragment that contains list of members of the band, also with Intent, and works perfectly.I used "this" for context.

Answer (score 0):

Add a web View

`Webview webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);`

And Write This code where you want a do the task

```
String url="Your Url";
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a *NullPointerException* at some point of your code. Probably at this line: `Tours.java:84`
But that code is not in yuor post..

Read: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I know that.But when I click on Tours.84, it shows me a class in which there is no line 84, and that makes no sense to me.I'll put the class into my code, so that you can see for yourself.

Comment: Your logcat said Tours.onDataChange(), where is that method?

Comment: You are changing the question all the time, accepting answer without being resolved.. This is not the way StackOverflow works